# PCF reports application crash each 5 minutes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, pcf, pcfdev

We have spring-boot batch task application that is hosted on pcf and deployed via spring-cloud-dataflow(scdf).

After we have connected it to app-dynamics agent it start to report crash every 5 minutes with the following resolution: 
[image]

[image]

But there is no any exceprion within application and there is no crashes.
In logs I can see plain app execution.

I was thinking that there is some problems with app health check configuration on pcf. So I have added health check, but problem still exists and I have no idea already what is wrong there.

Does anyone know how to fix this or have any ideas on why it can happen ?

Let me know if you need any additional info.Thx

@SabbyAnandan
We are using SCDF(1.3.0) and PCF(1.2)
There is nothing in SCDF logs. 
I suppose that is plain PCF issue that is reporting crash when there was no crashes/exception at all.

Comment: This seems incomplete without the versions. Could you please edit the post and update it with that information. Also, if this is reproducible, it'd be good if you can share the logs of SCDF and SKipper starting from when the deployment is triggered.

Comment: @SabbyAnandan We are using SCDF(1.3.0) and PCF(1.2) There is nothing in SCDF logs. I suppose that is plain PCF issue that is reporting crash when there was no crashes/exception at all.